# How to output an octave array as a org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, octave

I am trying to output a matlab/octave array as an org-mode table. So for an array/matrix like

```
a =[ 1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
```

I'd like to have a 3 by 2 org-mode table. I tried to just echo the array `a` as if in matlab, but it does not work. I am wondering how to make the output work.

More specifically, for an input array:

```
#+name: test-data
#+begin_src octave :session test_case :exports both
  a =[ 1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: test-data
: org_babel_eoe
```

I can generate its `size` as a table:

```
#+NAME: test-output-size
#+BEGIN_SRC octave :session test_case :results value :colnames yes :hline yes
  size(a)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-output-size
| 3 | 2 |
```

But when I tried to print the array `a` itself as a table, I got no output:

```
#+NAME: test-output-value
#+BEGIN_SRC octave :session test_case :results value :colnames yes :hline yes
  a
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-output-value
: org_babel_eoe
```

I also tried `disp()`, to no avail. So my question is:

*What is the proper way to output an array as a table?*

(This is with the Emacs 26 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave is peculiar (or maybe `ob-octave` is peculiar). In particular, the name `ans` seems to have special meaning. Try this:

```
#+name: test-data
#+begin_src octave :session test_case :exports both
  a =[ 1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
  ans = a
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: test-data
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the results to be the output (the default is `value`) and then use the `disp` option you already tried; place this

`:results output`

on the `begin_src` line.

Comment: I have found that this might not work to get table output. Instead, you might like to try `:results value table` and add the lin `1*a` as the last line of your src block.