# How to use a dynamic block (column view) as input to a babel function?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to use the table of an org-mode columnview dynamic block as input to a org-mode babel function. It works fine with static tables, but with the dynamic table, I get a "Reference not found" error.

```
* Assignment  
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       8055876A-873B-448D-8FC3-EDE2EB0C453D
  :END:

** TODO Basics  

*** TODO Basics A
Lorem ipsum

*** DONE Basics B  
Lorem ipsum

* Column view summary

#+name: data
#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 2 :id "8055876A-873B-448D-8FC3-EDE2EB0C453D" :maxlevel 3
| ITEM       | TODO | PRIORITY | TAGS |
|------------+------+----------+------|
| Assignment |      | B        |      |
|------------+------+----------+------|
| Basics     | TODO | B        |      |
| Basics A   | TODO | B        |      |
| Basics B   | DONE | B        |      |
#+END:

* Code for dynamic table fails 

#+begin_src python :results output :var data=data
  print("showing results")
  print(data)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:



* Static table 

#+name: somestatictable
| a | b |
|---+---|
| c | d |

* Access to static table works fine 

#+begin_src python :var staticdata=somestatictable  :results output
print("This works")
print(staticdata)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: This works
: [['c', 'd']]
```

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/use-org-babel-table-results-as-input-to-another-org-babel-snippet) seems related, but does not really help.

I am 99% sure I had this working with org-mode v8, but this error pops up with org-version 9.5.2 and 9.6.12. Any input appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you move the `#+name:` line inside the dynamic block? If so, maybe you can figure out a way to have the dynamic block function generate that line.

Comment: That actually works! Nice! And updating the dynamic block does NOT change the `#+name:` field, so that is also not a problem. Solved, thanks a lot!